# Covariates using SPSS mixed procedure

Tags: mixed-model, spss

I am analysing some data using SPSS mixed procedure to look at differences between conditions while accounting for nesting. As part of my model I would like to statistically "control" for two variables in the same way you might do with a multiple regression (i.e. entering a covariate into the model in a stepwise fashion and then examining the remaining variance explained by the IV of interest in the second step). One of my variables is categorical (education) and the other is scale (test results). Does placing both variables into the model as "covariates" (i.e. into the covariate box in the mixed menu) allow me to partial out their effects?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes is the short answer. But doing anything stepwise is often a bad idea; talking in terms of variance when you're doing mixed models is also worth avoiding. (Talk about log-likelihood instead.)

Comment: Thanks. I have read that even if I place the categorical covariate into the "factors" box of the menu, it will still be treated as a covariate relative to my DV, is that right?

Comment: Also, is there a long answer? I have looked for material that explains this, but can't find anything. Directions to a reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure. I always found trying to do mixed models with SPSS menus to be a nightmare, and used syntax - that (to me) was more intuitive. If you dummy code your categories first it will work though. Covariates in mixed models work just like covariates in regression. The book "Multilevel Analysis for Applied Research: It's Just Regression" might help you.